# Copy library from remote to local repo

Tags: maven, offline, artifactory, jcenter

I have an artifactory local repositoty in lan without Internet access.
Access to the Internet is possible only outside my enterprise.
But our team needs a little set of third-party libraries.
What is best way to import some libraries from jcenter or maven central to local repository?
Are there any tools or utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What people usually do it having a "durty" Artifactory instance outside of the DMZ. This instance is populating buy running the same build that you are running in the inside. Once the "durty" Artifactory instance is populated, the artifacts are verified and transferred to the "clean" Artifactory instance.

The procedure of the transfer depends on the stickiness of the governance and ranges from copying the artifacts on the flash drive, "whitening" them with the security team, and copying them to the "clean" instance, to the fully automatic replication by pulling the artifacts by  the "clean" Artifactory instance inside the DMZ to a "durty" repository. Those artifacts then verified and promoted to the "clean" repository, from which they are used.